# Magmi image import sets majority of product images, but not all

Tags: import, image, csv, magmi

I've been using Magmi to do a mass import of both product data and then going over the product data to reference product images via SKU. I've been able to get Magmi to import product data without issue, but have hit a snag with the image import.

Thing is, I've gone through some 10,000 products and was able to assign images to most of them against another CSV containing the product SKU and assigned images. And for a lot of the products, the base image, small image and thumbnails have been correctly assigned and show on the front-end.

However, there are still a significant amount of products that are not showing the small image and thumbnail on the front-end despite having the images assigned in the backend. I've been working most of this day going through reindexing, resetting the product images by overwriting the product data with blank images and redoing the image import, to messing around with the profile settings to see if it is something to do with the configuration.

The header of my image import CSV is as follows:

```
"sku", "image", "small_image", "thumbnail", "attribute_set", "type", "store", "product_websites", "visibility"
```

I'm not sure if I'm missing a specific needed field in which I must set in order cover all products on the update, since adding the visibility field seemed to work in getting most of them to display. Most, but not all unfortunately, and so far, the only way I can get a product that has been assigned an image via import to display all the images on the front-end is to manually edit it (set it to no image and then set it back). If I can solve this for the automatic import, then it'll save my client having to go through amending the images manually.

To note, I've made sure to reindex, clear cache, tweak configuration, over and over, whilst checking various support thread both on Stack Exchange and on other forums. So far, no success!

**EDIT** Nevermind, the solution is simple. Go nuclear and clear the whole catalog and reimport afresh. Images then uploaded and were assigned without issue. Tears of joy...

Comment: GDog87 I have the same problem ... but is not working even after I created thoese 2 columns. Do you have any ideea ... WHY ? Actually, there are 2 main issues: after import, I must enter in Admin to sellect catergory and to click on Base Image, Small Image and Thumbnail... is not such confortable for hundereds items :) I wait your kind reply if you know how to fix thoese 2 issues. CHeers

Comment: Ongoing issues with the import have yielded further insights for me. Basically, all my CSV import uses is the "sku", "image", "small_image", "thumbnail", and "media_image" fields. Nothing else. It seemed to work then when I wasn't trying to force extra fields into the import. That's the extent of what I've been able to gather, but I've encountered other problems since.

Comment: You seemed to have solved your issue, but, out of curiosity, what text editor and delimiter/encapsulation string were you using?

Answer (score 2):

Based on updates by the original poster, it sounds like * clear the whole catalog and re-import afresh* is one solution to this problem.

Answer (score 0):

The image label headers missing may have been causing the images not to go up? image_label thumbnail_label small_image_label etc?

So Please Make sure your Image Label Headers.

Comment: could you pls share csv eg